# Pythonic popping from a list to another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []
```

I want to move an element from list a, if it meets a certain condition.

```
a = [1,3]
b = [2]
```

The below code shows an example, however, I would like to do this inside of a single loop. How do I do this more efficiently?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []
pop_list = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 2:
        print("pop:", a[i])
        pop_list.append(i)

for i in range(len(pop_list)):
    b.append(a.pop(pop_list[i]))
# Reset pop_list
pop_list=[]
```

Ideally, I would not generate a new list b.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pair of list comprehensions would do the job: one to select the desired elements for `b`, the other to remove them from `a`

```
b = [i for i in a if i == 2]
a = [i for i in a if i != 2]
```

Comment: Clean pythonic approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` and `itertools.filterfalse` and use the same filtering function for both:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

a = [1,2,3]
b = []

list(filterfalse(lambda x: x == 2, a))
list(filter     (lambda x: x == 2, a))
```

```
[1, 3]
[2]
```

Here is the `itertools.filterfalse` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse).

Comment: Solution works well, does require me to modify your code slightly to
`a= list(filterfalse(lambda x: x == 2, a))
b=list(filter     (lambda x: x == 2, a))`

Comment: I don't see the difference

Comment: from itertools import filterfalse

a = [1,2,3]
b = []

list(filterfalse(lambda x: x == 2, a))
list(filter     (lambda x: x == 2, a))

>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print(b)
[]

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say

Comment: When I print out a after running the filter (at least in python 3.7.7), it does not update the values inside of the list. The values are not modified in place, but rather I get a copy?

Answer (score 1):

If the element `x` exists you could just remove it from `b` and append it to `a`.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = []
x = 2

def remove_append(a, b, x):
    if x in a:
        a.remove(x)
        b.append(x)

remove_append(a, b, x)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3]
[2]
```

Comment: Works well for a single element removal. @Wups, thank you for identifying a case I should have added.

Answer (score 1):

We must pass through all elements, however, you can apply this trick to add to the appropriate list in one loop:

(Appending to a loop is more efficient than deleting an element at arbitrary position)

```
a = [1,2,3]

condition_false, condition_true = [], []
for v in a:
    # Add to the right list
    (condition_false, condition_true)[v == 2].append(v)

# [1, 3]
print(condition_false)

# [2]
print(condition_true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single loop way that's similar to your initial method:

```
length = len(a) 
popped = 0 

for i in range(length):
    if i == length - popped: 
        break
    if a[i] == 2:
        b.append(a.pop(i))
        popped += 1
```

If we keep track of how many elements we pop from a, we can just stop our loop that many elements early since there are fewer elements left in a.

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` for `a=[2,2,2]`. `a` became shorter after pop, so you can't use the old index anymore.

Comment: ah good point, I only tested the case presented and didn't consider this one. Thank you